# using Jquery mouse events to detect if mouse is connected

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, mouseevent

I'm trying to detect whether a pointing device is being used on the page. `$(document).on('mouseover')` is being used to trigger a global variable, with the idea that any click before this happens signifies that a pointing device is not connected. Unfortunately, mousedown or pointerdown are triggering the mouseover BEFORE I have a chance to set a false value. Is there a way to catch the click before the mouseover fires? Is there something I can test for when the mouseover fires that will tell if the mousedown is also fired?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your approach is accurate, you won't be able to catch mouseover before mousedown, think about it... it's not natural that it happen that way. What are you actually trying to change in your web?

Comment: Basically, detecting if a mouse or touchpad is being used, as opposed to a touch screen.